# Dividing two identical floating point values doesn't result in 1

Tags: c, floating-point, pow

In my function:

```
const float EXPONENT = 1.8;
const uint8_t INDEX_MAX = 15;

uint8_t calcNewValue(uint8_t pwmIndex){
   uint8_t  pwmBaseValue = 255, result = 0;

   result = pow(pwmIndex, EXPONENT) / pow(INDEX_MAX, EXPONENT) * (pwmBaseValue);
   return result;   
}
```

When having a pwmIndex of 15 the "result" should read as: (15^1.8) / (15^1.8) * 255 resulting in 255.
But I get 254 instead. Why?

Update: I checked the code [here](https://ideone.com/iXZIJD) and it should work but it somehow doesn't on my 8 bit microcontroller.

Comment: probably because of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: `When having a pwmIndex of 15 the "result" should read as: (15^1.8) / (15^1.8) * 255 resulting in 255` - why??? It should be (15^1.8) / (255^1.8) * 255 resulting in 1.

Comment: @barak because it's 255*1 because dividing one value by itself equals 1

Comment: No it's not: `pwmIndex == 15 != 255 == INDEX_MAX`!!!

Comment: It does not help mixing `float` with `double`. Please use `double` unless there is very good reason not to. You don't use `short` for small integers do you? But, this won't solve the problems, because floating point is a trade-off between range and precision.

Comment: @barak my fault, that constant should've been 15 as well.

Comment: @WeatherVane where am I mixing float with double?
I updated my question with a link. It works there, but why not in my application?

Comment: The value 1.8 is `double` which is assigned to `float` so there is the first opportunity for inaccuracy (2 conversions, the first is `1.8` text to `double` the second is `double` to `float`). Also the arguments and return value from `pow` are `double`. You edited the question to mention *8 bit microcontroller* after I made that comment, perhaps it does not implement `double`.